# How can I get the checked attribute into Better Exposed Filters input type radios?

Tags: 8, forms

i'm having a BEF exposed filter representing a taxonomy, they're radios.

It works well, but when i select a radio, it won't get in its HTML tag the property «*checked*».
I guess the selected value of the radios is stored somehow at *$form_state*, but this prevents existence of «*checked*» tag at HTML level. :-(

at jQuery level, i can select and play with the «checked» property, so it's working at javascript level.

the person who does the CSS needs that «*checked*» property at HTML level ...
is there a way to insert it in the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

The person who does the CSS needs to design the dynamic property `:checked`, not the static attribute `[checked]`. The 2nd one is static in the HTML code and never updated after the intial page load, the first one is the currently selected input.